# How do you access the URL w react-redux to determine the user's progress in your application?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have the following container below:

What I would like to do is detect the user's URL...

if `/welcome/step1` set the step =1, if `/welcome/XXXX` set the step=2, etc...

With React Redux, what is the right way to detect the URL? And should I then be updating the state in the constructor?

**Welcome.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Welcome extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      step: 1
    };
  }
  showStep(props) {
    const {history} = this.props

    switch (this.state.step) {
      case 1:
        return <TBD />
      case 2:
        return <TBD />
    }
  }

  render() {
    var style = {
      width : (this.state.step / 4 * 100) + '%'
    }
    return (
      <main>
        <span className="progress-step">Step {this.state.step}</span>
        <progress className="progress" style={style}></progress>
        {this.showStep()}
      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default Welcome;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router).

To set it up, you'll want a `Root` component that looks something like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Welcome from './Welcome';

const Root = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/welcome/(:filter)" component={Welcome} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default Root;
```

And your `index.js` will need to be refactored to use the `Root` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Root from './components/Root'
import configureStore from '../configureStore'

const store = configureStore()

render(
  <Root store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Your `Welcome` component should now receive a `params` property that contains your URL parameter (e.g., `step1` or `step2`):

```
  constructor(props) {
    // props.params.filter == 'step1' || props.params.filter == 'step2'
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // we're going to remove everything in the string 
      // that isnt numerical with regex
      // e.g., 'step1' -> '1',  'step234' -> '234'
      step: props.params.filter.replace( /^\D+/g, '')
    };
  }
```

As far as setting it on the state, [it really depends on what you want to accomplish](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287). If you're just wanting to use it in the `render()` and `showStep()` methods, setting it on component state will be just fine.

More details on using `react-router` with Redux [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/UsageWithReactRouter.html).

Comment: Thanks but the Welcome component is not getting props.params -- how do I pass that along?

Comment: How are you rendering it? If Welcome has a parent component that is not the router, you'll need to do something like this: 
```const App = ({ params }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome
        filter={params.filter}
      />
    </div>
  );
};```

Comment: It does not have a parent. The router is the parent for Welcome

Comment: Do I maybe be to include so library to have access to params?

Comment: No, react-router should handle params.